# Why do ODEs that have solutions that have closed form solutions, *have* closed form solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why do certain classes of ODEs have closed form solutions? Is there something these classes have common apart from the fact that they have closed form solutions?

When I say "closed form", I mean something vague, like there is no finite combination of usual operators (addition, multiplication, powers, trigonometric and logarithmic operators) and operands that can be used to write the solution.

Comment: *Symmetry* is the key word to answer your question.

Comment: @Artem Symmetry?

Comment: A good (but involved) source is [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Applications-Differential-Equations-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387950001/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1420506157&sr=1-3&keywords=peter+olver) by Peter Olver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Determining whether series have "closed form" solutions is an incredibly difficult task.

For non-linear DEs this is done using "symmetry" techniques (as mentioned cryptically in the comments). Indeed Peter Olver's text is a good one for delving into this stuff. Other introductory texts are "Symmetry Methods for Differential Equations: A Beginner's Guide" by  Peter E. Hydon (this is a much lower level text than Olvers). Also, "Introduction to Symmetry Analysis" by Brian Cantwell. Cantwell's text has a wealth of information but is written to more of an engineering crowd.

The question of determining whether you can "solve" a differential equation, led to the development of a large branch of modern mathematics known as "Lie Theory" (named after Sophus Lie - pronounced "LEE"). Lie wanted to do for differential equations what Galois had done for polynomial equations.

Now if you restrict yourself to (systems) of *linear* differential equations, you can answer solvability by computing "differential Galois groups". Here the texts by Andy Magid ("Lectures on Differential Galois Theory") or Singer/van der Put ("Galois Theory of Linear Differential Equations") are good references. Although Crespo's "Algebraic Groups and Differential Galois Theory" would be where I started.

Here one looks are "symmetries" of differential field extensions and get an analogy of Galois theory for regular field extensions. If the differential Galois group of a differential field extension is "solvable", then the system of DEs is "solvable" in a very precise sense.

In Magid's book you can find proofs of things like: $\int e^{x^2}\,dx$ isn't an elementary function and the the [Airy equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) ($y''-xy=0$) is "unsolvable" (one can find series solutions but not your sort of "closed form" solutions).

All that said, whether there are "closed form" solutions or not is a *very* deep and difficult question to ask. It's even hard to formalize what you should mean by "closed form". :)

Comment: No royal road to understanding this, Bill?

Comment: Sorry, but some questions don't have easy answers. :)  Although the pursuit of the answer to your question has led to some super-awesome mathematics!

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderful answer anyway. At least I know where to look now :)